# How to show loading dialog while a long time query is executed?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, sqlcommand

I created a winforms app with .net 4.0.

First, I created a LoadingForm with cancel button, that must stop execution query.

I want to create an `ExecuteHelper` class and `LoadingForm` with cancellation query button.

```
public partial class LoadingFrm : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm
{
    private Action _cancel;

    public LoadingFrm(Action a)
    {
        _cancel = a;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }

    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.close();
        _cancel();
    }
}
```

Then, I create an `ExecuteHelper` class:

```
public class ExecuteHelper
{
    private readonly int tOut = 1000;
    private LoadingFrm _loadFrm;
    private SqlDataReader _result;
    private Task worker;
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private IAsyncResult iAr;
    private SqlCommand _command;

    ExecuteHelper()
    {
        _loadFrm = new LoadingFrm(CancelExecution);
    }

    public SqlDataReader Execute(SqlCommand command)
    {
        _command = command;
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var cToken = cts.Token;
        cts.Token.Register(() => _loadFrm.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() { _loadFrm.Close(); }));
        worker = new Task(() => { _loadFrm.ShowDialog(); }, cToken);
        SqlDataReader r = null;
        worker.Start();

        iAr = command.BeginExecuteReader();

        while (!iAr.IsCompleted)
        {
        }

        r = command.EndExecuteReader(iAr);
        cts.Cancel();
        return r;
    }

    public void CancelExecution()
    {
        _command.EndExecuteReader(iAr);
    }
}
```

Something is wrong, and it does not show the desired effect. Can anybody help?

Maybe this solution is right:

```
public static SqlDataReader Execute(SqlCommand command)
{
     var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
     var cToken = cts.Token;
     cToken.Register(() => { command.Cancel(); });

     Task<SqlDataReader> query = new Task<SqlDataReader>(new Func<SqlDataReader>(() => { return command.ExecuteReader(); }), cToken);
     LoadingFrm _loadingF = new LoadingFrm(() => { cts.Cancel(); });

     new Action(() => { _loadingF.Show(); }).Invoke();

     query.Start();
     query.Wait(30000, cToken);

     query.ContinueWith((obj) =>
     {
        _loadingF.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            _loadingF.Close();
        });
     });

     return query.Result;
}
```

Bur `query.start()` blocked the main thread and I can't click on button in loading form for cancel query execution.

Comment: What's the wrong effect you're getting? Like, is the loading form not displayed at all or is it being displayed in the background?

Comment: Really, i just don't know how to make the right. Now i crate another solution, but task.start() block main thread nad i can't click on button in loading form.

Comment: @user2223043, i try several solutions but, not effect

Comment: Well, you can try this. Remove the task creation from within the Exceute method. Create frm the Main thread a Task and assign the execute method to that Task which will make it run in the background. now the main thread is free. Create the Loading form object on this thread and call the showDialog(). This will execute your loading form on the main thread and blocks the current execution. Next if the user selects Cancel, close the form and return DialogResult.Cancel which you can then use to cancel the Execute Task.

Comment: what about using background worker? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

it simple and effective.

Comment: @avidenic, i want to learn Task )