# How to cancel execution sqlcommand?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, sqlcommand

I have a following method:

```
public void Test(SqlCommand command)
{
   command.ExecuteReader();
   Thread rThread2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { command.Cancel(); }));
   rThread2.Start();
}
```

But i can't cancel the sqlcommand while executing.

How i need change a code?
If possible, offer a solution with the tasks.

Comment: Curious as to what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: command.ExecuteReader is blocking.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ChrisBint, I want to show wait form for long time query. This form must cancel query if user click button cancel.

Comment: here description http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506620/how-to-show-loading-dialog-while-a-long-time-query-is-executed